# Creating A wifi hotspot in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, router

In my college dorm I have a wall jack with which I can connect to the internet.

I tried to create wifi hotspot with win 10 using the command

`NETSH WLAN set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Your_SSID key=Your_Passphrase`

But sadly this didn't give internet access to other devices. I suspect this might be because I needed to set a specific IP, subnet mask, default gateway and DNS in my IPv4 settings.

Is there someonway to make hotspot work? I also tried setting the same things in my android in advanced wifi settings but that didnt work either.

Comment: First and foremost: Are you sure this is even allowed? How does your internet access work? Did you give them your PC’s MAC address? Can you just plug in other devices? Can you connect multiple devices using a switch?

Comment: @DanielB No, MAC adress not given. Yes, i can plug in other devices freely, dont know if i can connect multiple devices though. Dont have a switch. Regarding if it's allowed or not, I'm not really sure. The thing is, hostel is wifi enabled but the router isn't near the room so no signals in the room. (I only need to give MAC address if I want to connect to the official Wi-fi. Ethernet can be connected without MAC, just need a unique IP for each room)

Comment: See [this answer written by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829382/wlanhostednetworkstartusing-or-how-windows-10-builtin-mobile-hotspot-works/50712007#50712007), w/explanation and working c++/code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="HotSpot" key=Password keyUsage=persistent
```

2.
From the Network and Sharing Center click on the “Change Adapter Settings” link in the top left hand corner.

3.
Enable the virtual adapter, if it is not already enabled, by right clicking on the adapter and pressing enable.

4.
When you have internet connectivity via the Ethernet cable and the virtual adapter is enabled, right click on the “Local Area Connection” button and click “Properties”. Once the dialogue box appeared, click on the “Sharing” tab, then click the check box labeled “Allow other Network Users to connect through this Computer's Internet Connection”.

5.
Click on the drop down box “Home networking connection” labeled “Select a private network connection” and select the "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter" which should be labeled like “Wireless Network Connection 2”.

6.
Click “OK” and the “Local Area Connection” button should now say “Shared”.

To start hotspot:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

To stop:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
```

On Windows 8 and above:

Open PC Settings in the Settings charm, then browse to Network->Connections.

Select your mobile network, then slide the "Share this connection" option to "On". (The option won't appear if the connection isn't a mobile one.)

Comment: That was easy..Thanks dude. (I used the second method btw, but this helps other users too!)